# How to get an integer from standard input in ARMSIM# (Without using scanf?)

Tags: assembly, arm

So I've been googling for two days with no luck about this issue. I'm using ARMSIM# and nowhere in the manual does it explain how to get an integer from Stdin, much less how to use it! Is there a simpler method to do it without using scanf? If not, how do I do it with scanf? I don't know the syntax (or library call?) to be able to use scanf, it gives me an "unknown symbol error".

*MODS, please don't link this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28000988/read-from-stdin-in-armsim) as an answer. It doesn't work.

Comment: Having just tried ARMsim 1.9.1, SWI_ReadInt on file descriptor #0 _does_ work as expected if stdin is set up to come from a text file (in preferences). Looks like it's just buggy...

Comment: Could you explain this in more detail? This sounds intriguing. Do I just put ".txt" in the preferences? and then what would the syntax look for the file descriptor 0 etc?

Comment: Er, not really. I looked at the preferences window and it seemed fairly clear that putting paths to files in the labelled text boxes would redirect I/O. I tried that and indeed it did. Also the browse and output mode buttons didn't work, which furthered my belief in the whole standard I/O implementation being a bit crap.

Answer (score 1):

Assembly is completely different from C (scanf,...). Assembly works directly on the chip and uses its registers and periphery directly (registers, ALU, GPIO, interfaces like TWI,...)

For an example see this thread [Assembly: Read integer from stdin, increment it and print to stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495530/assembly-read-integer-from-stdin-increment-it-and-print-to-stdout)

This is for IA32 assembler, ARM assembler is again different, i.e. the syscall for reading from stdin has another number,...

In this thread is ARM assembler: [Reading and Printing a string in arm assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053510/reading-and-printing-a-string-in-arm-assembly)

For reading an integer from a file in ARMSIM you use the syscall **SWI 0x6a** (STDIN is treated as a file internally, in most cases (always) has FD0)

The file handle (file descriptor) for STDIN is **0**

In this git is some armsim code but it is unfinished (faulty)https://github.com/lseelenbinder/armsim/blob/master/test_files/sim2/sim2os/armos.c  **<-errors pay attention**

In the following code the pdf http://cas.ee.ic.ac.uk/people/gac1/Architecture/Lecture10_5.pdf is used as a reference for the ARM SWIs (syscalls)

According to this pdf the SWI 0x6a reads a given number of bytes from a file handle. Now the encoding of the input is important normally it is KeyCode, see this http://cas.ee.ic.ac.uk/people/gac1/Architecture/Lecture10_5.pdf and this http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ (For capital letters and numbers KeyCode and ASCII are identic)
So when a key is stroke on the keyboard 1 byte appears in STDIN 
So the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 all consist of 1 bytes (see the KeyCode/ASCII table). If you want to read a 4 digit number you have to read 4 bytes

```
 AREA read_from_stdin, CODE

.equ SWI_Open, 0x66    ;open a file
.equ SWI_Close,0x68    ;close a file
.equ SWI_PrChr,0x00    ; Write 1 byte to file handle
.equ SWI_RdBytes, 0x6a ; Read n bytes from file handle
.equ SWI_WrBytes, 0x69 ; Write n bytes to file handle
.equ Stdin, 0          ; 0 is the file descriptor for STDIN
.equ Stdout, 1         ; Set output target to be Stdout
.equ SWI_Exit, 0x11    ; Stop execution

ENTRY

START mov R0,#0        ; the file handle from that is read has to be in R0 the file handle for STDIN is 0
adr R1, =buffer        ; load address of the buffer in which is read to R1
mov R2,#4              ; read 4 bytes for a 4 digit number (4 characters)
swi 0x6a               ; invoke system call 0x6a
                       ; now type a number, the corresponding KeyCode  should appear in buffer
; to print the content of buffer do

mov R0,#1              ; write to stdout
adr R1, =buffer        ; move address of buffer in R1 to write the content of buffer
mov R2,#4              ; write 4 bytes (4 characters)
swi 0x69               ; invoke system call 0x69
                       ; this should write the content of buffer you typed to stdout

buffer % 4             ; reserve buffer 4 byte

END
```

**Maybe this contains syntax errors, i only know ARM assembly not ARMSIM#**

The problem with this is that reading 4 bytes (char) from stdin does not make these 4 bytes an int (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science) ). When a key is stroke on the keyboard there appear KeyCode-/ASCII-coded characters in STDIN, you have to make an int of them... (i would skip all ASCII-characters that are no numbers at first...)

Comment: This is looking great. I think the first two links are duplicate though :O but otherwise thank you so much for taking the time to write this. So what you're saying is I should be able to use SWI 0x6c to grab whatever is in inside my STDIN? When you say find the file handle for STDIN, what exactly do you mean?